# cURL throws 504 gateway timeout error with external website on my vps

Tags: timeout, curl, 504

The following returns a gateway timeout on my vps (debian, squeeze)

```
 curl --head http://www.flipkart.com/
 HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
```

But works fine i.e gives a 302 HTTP on my home computer. 
So I guess something is wrong in my vps settings. But what?

The same command was working fine yesterday.

Help!

Edit: PHP-cURL throws a 504 as well, which is how this problem was discovered..

Edit2: 
Other sites work just fine though:

```
 curl --head https://google.com
```

Edit3: I can successfully ping to flipkart.com

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem with your VPS?

Comment: same command works fine i.e gives a 200 HTTP from my home computer.

Comment: That's funny, because I get an instant 504 error. Which means the remote site is doing something stupid. This isn't your problem.

Comment: But if the remote site can be accessed with a browser, it should be accessible from curl as well . right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!! It was giving 504 when curl tries to resolve to ipv6

On comparing the requests, the only difference was the ip address.

So I tried forcing ipv4 resolving via

```
curl -4 --head  http://www.flipkart.com
```

and it worked!

Comment: See, I told you the remote site was doing something stupid. :)

Comment: Indeed. My solution is more like a workaround.